# An error occurred in a Service Broker/Database Mirroring transport connection endpoint, Error: 8474, State

Tags: sql, sql-server, endpoint, service-broker, database-mirroring

Error Log Generated this Error:

> An error occurred in a Service Broker/Database Mirroring transport
>   connection endpoint, Error: 8474, State: 11. (Near endpoint role:
>   Target, far endpoint address: '') Error: 9642, Severity: 16, State: 3.

It is generated against several environments at the same time. We don't have mirroring enabled but have Service Broker enabled. Which is working fine. Any clues what could be the reason for this error?

Comment: I don't have much to give you. But as a question - do the environments that this occurred on share anything in common? The message mentions that the server in question is in the Target role for Service Broker. Do they, for instance, share an initiator? Or, if not, are the initiators on a common network?

Comment: They don't share an initiator, but yes they are on a common network.

Comment: As for the common network, was there perhaps a temporary loss of connectivity between Target and Initiator?

Comment: I don't think there was any loss of communication.